# How to get all document fields in a subcollection appear at the same time

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I just need some help on getting a document field on firestore database. Sample image [image sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzabD.jpg) on the link is my user sub collection. I was trying to get all the document field "groupName" and make it appear all on the screen. With the code I am using only one field appears on the screen.

```
  class CreateNewGroup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = ({
       groupName: '',
       loading: false,

    });
  };

  getCoordinates(query) {
    console.log('start loading animation');
  };

 MountFSUserGroup = () => {
 const curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

 const dbUser =
  firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(curUser.uid)
  .collection('SampleGroup') 
  .get()  
  .then(snapshot => {
     if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
        return;
     }  
     snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data()); 
        const { groupName } = doc.data();
        this.setState({ groupName, loading: false }); 

     });
   })
   .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
   });  

  const { groupName } = dbUser;
  this.setState({ groupName, loading: true }); 
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.MountFSUserGroup()
  }; 

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.MountFSUserGroup()
    console.log("user group mounted");
  };      


  render() {

  return (
     <View style={{flex: 1,}}>
        <CustomHeaderBack />
        <Loader loading={this.state.loading} />

        <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.body}>
              <View style={styles.titleCont}>
              <Text 
                 style={styles.text1}>
                    SAMPLE GROUP LIST
              </Text>         
              </View> 

              <View style={styles.insideCont}>
              <Text 
                 style={styles.text2}>
                    Select Your Group:
              </Text>


              <Text 
                 style={styles.text2}>
                    {this.state.groupName}

              </Text>


              </View>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <CustomFooter />
     </View>    
     )
    }
    };

     export default CreateNewGroup ;
```

[Sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQb5J.jpg) shows only the third field " groupName: "Group Three" " is showing but on the console [(console log sample)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkJsQ.jpg) all of the fields are listing at the same time.

if I use

```
  .where('groupName', "==", true)
```

it goes to the empty error message "No matching document" and the screen freezes. Hoping someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: wait.. you are merely storing ONE groupName.. so my guess it that it is showing the last one. I do not think this is a data retrieval problem as your console log seems alright. I think you need to `snapshot.map()` and set that to your component state (assuming react)

Comment: yes im using react native cli. I did try snapshot.docs.map() but the result is still the same, console logs all document field but nothing is showing on the screen compared to not using map there is one field showing.

Comment: I also did snapshot.map() just now and it's just loading continuously.

Comment: umm.. where do you have this code? It is probably getting called on render/mount and is changing the state, causing the component to render, which is calling the fn and so on. You might want to call this on condition.. or if you are using hooks, wrap the call in useEffect.. conditioned on the current user id? probably...

Comment: this code comes from firebase docs. The function is inside component. I am not that familiar with hooks I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: can you post the component code? where are you calling `MountFSUserGroup`?

Comment: I have posted the whole code above

Answer (score 0):

<s>There are couple of problems with the code as it stands.</s>

`this.setState({ groupName, loading: false });` - this is setting just the last encountered groupName to the component state. Which is the original problem. You will have to `snapshot.map()`

If it is constantly re-rendering, then this fn is probably called in the render cycle somewhere. As a general principle, it is always better to differentiate data retrieval and state management as much as possible. So, if you move the getGroupNames into a function of its own, and supply the user id and firebase instance, you can then set the value to state only if it is different from the previous values.

Or, if you are using hooks, which I would strongly suggest if you can, then use `useMemo` or set up the call using `useEffect` depending on the user id. Either way will limit the calls to only when required.

Something like this would do?

```js
//...imports...

class CreateNewGroup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = ({
       groupNames: [],
       loading: false,
    });
  };

//i might even take this out of the component and declare it as a pure js function
// as it is not using anything from 'this' and loading can be set where it is being called from too
 getFSUserGroup = async () => {
    try {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
        const curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        // get some value
        const data = async firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(curUser.uid)
            .collection('SampleGroup') 
            .get()  
            .map(doc =>  doc.data().groupName); // get all the group names for each item
        this.setState({ loading: false }) // set loading as false, will trigger a render
        return data // return that data from above
    } catch (e) {
        // failed to get documents
        this.setState({ loading: false })
    }// if it errored or something, it would return undefined
}


  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFSUserGroup().then(x => {
        if (x && !this.state.groupNames) {
            this.setState({ groupNames })
        }
        // it might not be a great idea to simply `!this.state.groupNames` though.. :(
    })


  }; 
// render and other stuff
```

Also, if you are starting out.. it might be a good idea to look at [React Stateless Function Components](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc) because then you can use [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)
which amongst other things, neatly abstracts a lot of the boiler plate code involved in doing simple tasks like the one you are doing.
For a good intro into whys and hows take a look at [this one](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-fdbde8803889)

Comment: I am not that familiar with hooks. I am still a beginner with react native

Comment: It says .map' is undefined....I did try to use Flatlist on the previous code and it is now showing on the screen but the text that is showing on the screen says "undefined" more than 10x. And yes I think it's time to learn hooks.

Comment: Finally solve my problem, instead of using map I used push for doc.data() which I also found here on this website similar problem to mine